# Tailwindcss - How to use .class selector?

Tags: less, tailwind-css

I am switching from Ant Design(which is using LESS) to use Tailwindcss.
Overall Tailwindcss is great to use, but I notice some of the problem in it.

in LESS, it is easier to override a styles by locating the css classname and use `.class` selector to modify its css.

For example, this snippet is used to override styles on `ql-container` and `ql-toolbar`.

```
.container {
  [class*="ql-container"] {
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  }

  [class*='ql-toolbar'] {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  }
}
```

However, how can I do the same in Tailwindcss? It is doable? Or I should stick back to LESS or even pure CSS to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: How about using just `.container{ & .ql-container{...} & .ql-toolbar{...} }`?

Comment: Is this pure CSS? I am not sure on this but class selector will auto locate wherever the class's name is matched regardless how the class is being nested. 
By using your method, if let say `ql-container` is nested in 3 classes, this method wont not be working I think.

Comment: and also.. if using your method, how can I achieve the same in tailwindcss?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. If you want to tweak the base implementation of the `tailwind.css` classes, `tailwind.config.css` is your place to do.

*Example Code in `tailwind.config.css`:*

```
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,js}'],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      'blue': '#1fb6ff',
      'purple': '#7e5bef',
      'pink': '#ff49db',
      'orange': '#ff7849',
      'green': '#13ce66',
      'yellow': '#ffc82c',
      'gray-dark': '#273444',
      'gray': '#8492a6',
      'gray-light': '#d3dce6',
    },
    fontFamily: {
      sans: ['Graphik', 'sans-serif'],
      serif: ['Merriweather', 'serif'],
    },
    extend: {
      spacing: {
        '8xl': '96rem',
        '9xl': '128rem',
      },
      borderRadius: {
        '4xl': '2rem',
      }
    }
  },
}
```

#### 2. If you want to override the existing style with added functionality

*Example: If you want `text-8xl` to have underline with its initial class implementation uneffected. Change in the `base.css` class*

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  [class~="text-8xl"] {
    @apply text-8xl underline;  text-8xl now has underline aswell
  }
}
```